# Access ALSA as systemd system service running as a regular user

Tags: linux, systemd, pulseaudio, alsa, d-bus

I have a service which uses both the network and sound(ALSA), and I'm trying to make a systemd system service out of it. It works as a user service, but I can't make it work as a system service.

```
dbus-run-session[16623]: ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:
dbus-run-session[16623]: Alsa error PCM open ALSA function 'snd_pcm_open' failed with error 'ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused'
dbus-run-session[16623]: Could not start audio: Alsa error: PCM open failed
```

Here's what I have so far. It's a template unit, the parameter is my user name.
Commented out the sandboxing settings.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/spotifyd@.service
[Unit]
Description=A spotify playing daemon
Documentation=https://github.com/Spotifyd/spotifyd
Wants=sound.target
After=sound.target
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=%i

Type=exec
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dbus-run-session /usr/local/bin/spotifyd --no-daemon

Restart=always
RestartSec=12

ProtectSystem=full
#ProtectSystem=strict

#ProtectHome=tmpfs
#TemporaryFileSystem=/home/%i
#BindPaths=/home/%i/.config/pulse
#BindReadOnlyPaths=/home/%i/.local/share/

#ProtectHome=read-only
#ReadWritePaths=/home/%i/.config/pulse
#ReadOnlyPaths=/home/%i/.local/share/

#PrivateTmp=true
#NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comments:

- The daemon is not compiled with pulseaudio support, only ALSA. Not sure if that would matter.
- `dbus-run-session` is needed otherwise it fails at startup, since it register a d-bus name.
- I prefer it as a system service instead of a user one because I can depend on the network-online
- I'm running the service with my user, but could be a new user as well, as long as I have d-bus/MPRIS working
- I don't want to run PulseAudio/ALSA as a system service
- Group=audio didn't work

So what's wrong with the audio setup? I expected a system service switched to a regular account to have the same outcome as a user service.

Comment: Is that user in the `pulse-access` group?

Comment: @CL. no, it isn't. Adding it to the Group/SupplementaryGroups didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

> I expected a system service switched to a regular account to have the same outcome as a user service.

It can be, although one thing is not shared: the environment.

This was required to successfully access ALSA. (Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error)

```
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

Which makes me realize I should just run as an user service. The lifetime of the system service and the user session don't match.