# no alsa-sound in systemd-service (using screen)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd, gnu-screen, alsa

I just set up a `systemd.service` in order to run [cmus](https://github.com/cmus/cmus) (a console-music-player) detached to a [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) at startup.

i **don't** get sound, when starting via remote with no user logged in to the machine.
i **do** get sound, while i'm logged in as the user i set the service to run. but: i can't change volume via remote, it says "mixer is not open".

when i just start cmus detached to a screen logged in as the user manually, i can log out again, and **do** have sound and mixer via remote.

when i set the service to run as root (which i don't want, for several reasons) it **does** have sound and mixer.

unfortunately `Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587124/access-alsa-as-systemd-system-service-running-as-a-regular-user) doesn't help (1000 is the right one).

so the question is: what is missing here to get `alsa` fully working in my systemd-service as a user?

my current unit looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=cmusd (consolemusicplayer in screen with remote-web-server)
After=syslog.target network.target sound.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=myusername
WorkingDirectory=/home/myusername/cmus_daemon
ExecStart=/home/myusername/cmus_daemon/cmusd.init start
ExecStop=/home/myusername/cmus_daemon/cmusd.init stop
Environment="HOME=/home/myusername" "USERNAME=myusername"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where `cmusd.init` start does basically

```
screen -dmS cmusplayer cmus --listen $CMUS_IP
```

my system is a ubuntu server 19.10 on a small board with optical audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allright, after more searching and experimenting i found a solution, that works like a charme at least on this ubuntu: just add `Group=audio`. No environment needed.

```
[Unit]
Description=cmusd (consolemusicplayer in screen with remote-web-server)
After=syslog.target network.target sound.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=myusername
Group=audio
WorkingDirectory=/home/myusername/cmus_daemon
ExecStart=/home/myusername/cmus_daemon/cmusd.init start
ExecStop=/home/myusername/cmus_daemon/cmusd.init stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```